# Graphing a given function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, elementary-functions

How to graph a function like $f(x)=e^{x^2}+\cos x$ using pen and paper? I mean without using any graphing calculators. What should be the approach for finding whether the function is one one or many one and into or onto?

Comment: Notice that the first term dominates... by a *LOT*.

Comment: I could not understand.please explain

Comment: Which is *LARGER*, $e^{x^2}$ or $\cos x$?  Is it by a lot, or by a just a little?  If you are unsure, try graphing them.  Or plugging in $x = 1000$.

Answer (score 0):

Do a discussion:
Find zeros. Find zeros of the first derivative (local mins and maxs). Find zeros of the second derivative (points of inflection, concave / convex intervals). Check for symmetry (e.g. $f(x)=f(-x)$). Compute the limits. With such a discussion, you should get a good idea about how the graph looks like.